# Can I dye a sports bra to get rid of writing on the band

Tags: clothing

I [image]

I just bought a very cute sports bra from Fashion Nova. However it has white lettering that says “selfie” on it which I dislike highly. Can I dye the white lettering so that I can’t see it or should I do something else?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you want to keep the white strips around the armholes, I wouldn’t dump the whole item in dye - and dyeing synthetic fabrics can be tricky anyway.

In true lifehacks style, I would simply grab a black permanent marker and start coloring the text. If you stretch the band a bit, you’ll cover more of the white. Repeat if some of the marker washes off after a few rounds in the washer.

Answer (score 2):

It looks as though the elastic band with the word "Selfie" is at the very bottom of the sports bra, and there are a few inches of looser material above it. One simple way to hide the printing is to simply fold the elastic band up underneath the looser material when you wear it.

If this works, you can make this solution more permanent. When you are *not* wearing the bra, fold the elastic band under, and then sew it to the loose material. Since it is elastic, you should sew in one 1/2" spot, then in another 1/2" spot a few inches away, then another 1/2" spot. This should allow the elastic to stretch while keeping it attached to the loose material.